# How to remove all lines, line by line from a file?

Tags: file, python-2.7

I'm running a loop that takes names from a file.

What I want to do is when the name is taken, it then deletes it from the file. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try out [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html).

It goes something like:

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input(someFileName, inplace=True):
    doSomething()
```

Any line iterated over is consumed, hence deleted from the file.
If you need to keep it just `print` it, it'll be rewritten to the file in the same location.
i.e. if you won't print the line back it'll disappear :)

Answer (score 0):

Native files don't work that way. You'd have to rewrite the entire list of remaining files, each time through the loop. Performance will be bad (unless the list of files is always very short). And the failure modes are very bad if your process crashes while you're trying to update the file because you can't do the update in place. The best you could do is: write to a temp file, delete the original file, then rename (or move) the temp file.

Instead, you should consider using [SQLite](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html). You could either delete records from a `File` table, or have a status field that tracks which files have been processed.

Comment: @user1628593, is there anything else I can do to make this answer more acceptable to you?